# Setting Java Heap Size does not work with 256GB RAM 64-bit machine

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

I have been trying to find the answer to this but I still could not.

I have a 64-bit machine with 256 GB RAM.

I am trying to execute a Java program which links to MySQL. And it needs a quiet big heap size because when I used VM argument `-Xmx1024m` after few minutes this pops up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

But, when I tried to set the program VM argument by `-Xmx2048m` or bigger, it does not work and said:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

I read that setting `-Xmx2048` is not a problem for 64-bit machine but I really do not know why it's not working on my machine.

`java -version` output:
[image]

**wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory /Value** output:

```
FreePhysicalMemory=251663664
```

**wmic computersystem get TotalPhysicalMemory** output:

```
TotalPhysicalMemory
274811621376
```

**wmic os get osarchitecture** output

```
OSArchitecture
64-bit
```

I could not execute `systeminfo|find "Memory"` as it says wrong syntax. Im not sure why either.

Comment: What is the output of `java -version` on your command line?

Comment: I updated my question with java -version output.

Comment: What happens if you try `-Xmx64g` ?

Comment: when i tried -Xmx64G it says: Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx64g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.

Comment: What's the output of `systeminfo |find "Memory"`

Comment: And what's the output of `wmic os get osarchitecture`

Comment: I think where we're both going here is checking the arch of OS, PowerShell, and the JVM

Comment: I updated the question with those answers. Unfortunately my computer is in Korean and I have no idea about those Korean language there. I am not really familiar with checking those stuff but I will try.

Comment: Hmm, the fact that we're on a Korean windows does not make things easier :) Anyway, to sum up: Make sure your OS is 64-Bit, that it "sees" the RAM (check in Task-Manager) and that your JVM is 64-bit and then you should be good to go. Otherwise I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: Any difference is you launch powershell from `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` ?

Comment: @elviravelia Seems like instead of `systeminfo|find "Memory"` you run `systeminfo|find"Memory"` (without a space between `find` and `"Memory"`).

Comment: Please try this command line > **wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory /Value** and **wmic computersystem get TotalPhysicalMemory**

Comment: Just to be sure - you're running your program from console, not some kind of IDE?

Comment: You can go to control panel > region and language to change the locale from Korean to English or your prefered one. @Droidekas what's the problem with that much RAM?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc,its just a lot.I know not an appropriate place but it was quite fascinating  a fact.

Comment: @Droidekas I think it may be a lot with a Java program but not with other languages that compile to native code, as some program may need TB of memory

Comment: @Deltharis I run my program from Eclipse.

Comment: @biology.info I tried and added the result to my question

Comment: That adds another layer where the problem might lay. Elicpse does not necceserily use java from JAVA_HOME (which was what caused me problems the last time I faced something like this), check project specific settings. Also, while I'm not certain, using 32 bit Eclipse could possibly cause such problems. If nothing works it would be best to try and run the program from console with java -jar and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @all the program runs fine on console. So apparently the problem is on Eclipse. I will try to find whats wrong with my Eclipse. Thanks all for helping. I am sorry that I missed the thought to try it on console and posted it here..

Answer (score 1):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

This message implies the java heap does not have enough space to do further allocation.
It seems you have set to 1G of Xmx which is insufficient for your application 
else the application might leak memory which occupies space in java heap.

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

During VM initialization. JVM does various init right from Heap to JIT modules.
Java heap are continiuos space while doing doing initialization if JVM could not find the
contigous memory space for the requested Xmx then above error message will be thrown.

These are virtual memory allocation so please do not confuse with physical memory values

Please run the command
java -verbose:init -Xmx2048 -version

this command will tell the steps undergoes by JVM while doing initialization  and during what step it got failed.

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted. If it is quoted, cite the source.

Answer (score 0):

Consider running your app as an administrator - just launch the PowerShell console via right click -> Run as Administrator.

Windows may deny granting a lot of memory to a single process that is running non-elevated.

Also - are you using Windows Server or a workstation version of Windows? It is generally recommended to use Windows Server for such "big" services.